# WebRequest падает скорость в многопоточном приложении

Tags: c#

Суть вопроса вот в чем. Есть класс, в нем функция отправки сообщения с WebRequest в отдельном потоке с бесконечном цикле, с задержкой в 1 секунду. Создаем массив этого класса, например 10 элементов. Циклом пробегаемся по массиву, в запускаем потом на бесконечную отправку сообщений. И чем больше элементов в массиве, тем дольше будет отправка. Хотя, если не делать массив, а запустить разные копии программы, то отправка сообщений будет мгновенная. Приложу абстрактный код ниже

```
    class Request {
       public void Start() {
          new Thread(()=>{
             while(true) {
                SendRequest();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
             }
          }).Start();
       }
    }

public Main() {
   var requests = new List<Request>();
   requests.Add(new Request());

   foreach(var request...) {
      request.Start();
   }
}
```

Comment: 1) попробуйте отправлять запросы асинхронно 2) используйте для отправки [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Кстати, получается, что вы генерите кучу потоков, и чем больше потоков, тем медленней работает программа. Я поясню - в многопоточном приложении переключение между потоками - дорогая операция по ресурсам и времени. Таким образом, чем больше потоков - тем больше переключений между потоками, тем больше времени тратится на переключение и меньше на полезную работу. Другими словами, если вы создадите много много потоков, ваша программа не будет работать быстрее, а скорее всего просто зависнет, так как все время будет тратиться на переключение между потоками.

Comment: tym32167, спасибо большое, обязательно все попробую

Comment: Штука в том, что сейчас, когда вы создаете 100500 потоков, то бОльшую часть времени каждый поток либо ждет ответа от сервера, либо ждет Thread.Sleep() - то есть, по сути, простаивает. Если вы переделаете на асинхронные запросы, то вам не поняобится куча потоков, так как асинхронная операция не занимает поток вовсе. А раз будет меньше потоков - то меньше переключений между ними, и, как следствие, все должно работать побыстрее

Comment: @tym32167 а почему не ответом?

Comment: @rdorn добавил ответом

Answer (score 3):

Получается, что вы генерите кучу потоков, и чем больше потоков, тем медленней работает программа. Я поясню - в многопоточном приложении переключение между потоками - дорогая операция по ресурсам и времени. Таким образом, чем больше потоков - тем больше переключений между потоками, тем больше времени тратится на переключение и меньше на полезную работу. Другими словами, если вы создадите много много потоков, ваша программа не будет работать быстрее, а скорее всего просто зависнет, так как все время будет тратиться на переключение между потоками.

Штука в том, что сейчас, когда вы создаете 100500 потоков, то бОльшую часть времени каждый поток либо ждет ответа от сервера, либо ждет Thread.Sleep() - то есть, по сути, простаивает. Если вы переделаете на асинхронные запросы, то вам не поняобится куча потоков, так как асинхронная операция не занимает поток вовсе. А раз будет меньше потоков - то меньше переключений между ними, и, как следствие, все должно работать побыстрее.

То есть вам надо:

- Попробуйте отправлять запросы асинхронно
- используйте для отправки [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

Как пример (за корректность не ручаюсь - не запускал, но идея должна быть понятна)

```
public class Request
{
    private bool _runned = false;

    public async void Start()
    {
        _runned = true;
        while(_runned)
        {
            await SendRequest("http://google.com");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _runned = false;
    }

    private static async Task<string> SendRequest(string url)
    {
        using(var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            // do smthg
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

По моему с версии c# 4.0 рекомендуется использовать класс Task, а не Thread. Task будет использовать потоки из пула потоков. Если вкратце, то пул оптимизирован для выделения потоков.

Comment: `Task будет использовать потоки из пула потоков` - это не совсем верно. Это, во первых, зависит от того, как таск создан. Во вторых, таски могут вообще не использовать потоки. Таски - это такая абстракция кусочка какой то работы, а как она выполняется - это скрыто внутри таска.

Comment: Если использовать стандартный Task.Run() или Task.Factory.StartNew() то будет использоваться пул. Остальные случаи бывают очень редко (ни разу не видел самописный task scheduler). Ну и результат из Taska можно вернуть сразу, тогда поток использоваться не будет, но это тоже редкий случай.

Comment: Метод `Task.Factory.StartNew()` содержит много параметров, ему можно явно указать, что таск нуждается в отдельном потоке или даже можно передать свой шедулер. Но это не важно, так как тут сам клиент поддерживает асинхронные операции и вручную таски создавать не нужно. Поглядите на мой ответ - я нигде не создавал таски, но они есть.

Comment: Я с вами полностью согласен, просто я хотел объяснить человеку, что использовать thread это не очень хорошо. И в его коде Thread.Start можно заменить на Task.Run

Comment: К сожаленнию, это тоже не поможет, так как поместив много задач пул потоков, пул не будет их выполнять все разом, а будет выполнять пачками по очереди, что тоже будет работать медленно. Самый оптимальный вариант - не использовать ни потоки, ни пул потоков, а ожидать ответов от сервера асинхронно.

Comment: Тогда вопрос. При асинхронном вызове мы запоминаем контекст синхронизации, а саму задачу с высокой долей вероятности выполняем в другом потоке. Если мы в цикле вызовем большое кол-во асинхронных задач, где они будут выполняться?

Comment: при асинхронном вызове, который задействует периферию (например, сеть или ввод-вывод), то да, мы запоминаем контекст синхронизации, но сама задача нигде не выполняется, она не задействует ни поток, ни процессор. То есть с точки зрения процессора - ничего не происходит. Когда же приходит ответ от периферии о завершении задачи, тогда запускается так называемое продолжение - либо на пуле потоков, либо в захваченном контексте, либо ещё где то

Comment: Например, поглядите на код в моем ответе. Я там насоздавал кучу задач на скачиваение. Так вот если запустить это все в UI потоке, то есть в потоке где установлен контекст синхронизации, то все продолжения будут продолжаться в UI потоке и никакой пул задействован не будет. Если же контекст синхронизации не установлен, то все продолжения будут продолжаться на пуле потоков - то есть в нескольких потоках сразу. Но сами запросы к серверам в моем примере процессор в любом случае не тратят.

Comment: И какой вы думаете будет при этом выигрыш? В httpclient везде стоит configurawait false, и при большом количестве асинхронных задач их продолжения так же будут забивать пул. Я не пытаюсь с вами спорить, просто не уверен, что здесь все так однозначно.

Comment: `httpclient везде стоит configurawait false` - ткните пальцем, где стоит? По идее такого быть не должно. По поводу асинхронности. Вот смотрите, если мы запускаем синхронные таски через Task.Run (то есть просто меняем создание потока на создание таска в примере автора), то каждый наш таск займет какой то поток, например, 10 тасков создадутся и отправятся в пул, 10 тасков будут ждать, пока первая десятка пул не освободит. Если же мы запускаем таски асинхронно, то они все стартуют сразу, просто одновременно будут работать 10 продолжений. Но продолжение таска просто проверяет условие цикла и все

Comment: что означает, что продолжение таска будет занимать поток на очень короткое время.

Comment: Другими словами, представьте, что вы покупаете билет на автобус в билетном автомате. В синхронном случае (треды просто на Task.Run) - вы подходите к автомату, покупаете билет и стоите и ждете у этого автомата пока не придет время автобуса. Как только подъезжает автобус, вы пробиваете в этом автомате билет и отходите от него в автобус. То есть, пока вы не уехали, никто больше купить билет не может.

Comment: А в асинхронном варианте, вы подходите к автомату, покупаете билет и отходите от него. Когда видите свой автобус, то подходите к автомату снова, пробиваете билет и идете к автобусу. То есть, пока вы ждете автобус, ещё много народу может купить билет

Comment: так вот автомат билетный - это поток, вы - таск, ожидание автобуса - ожидание переферии, пробивка билета перед отъездом - продолжение таска.